# ROS connectivity and usernames

Tags: rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I've just discovered a really dumb mistake on my part and I want confirmation as to whether this matters. On two machines (one of which is the ROS_MASTER, c1), my username is `ibrahim`, but on some other machines that are connected to the ROS_MASTER through openvpn on the PR2 basestation, my username is `ibrahima`. On the machines with username `ibrahima` I can read topics fine, but I can't access services. Does ROS assume that you can ssh with the same username into other machines? I have set up an ssh config file (~/.ssh/config) such that I can ssh without having to type the proper username but I still can't get services to work. For example, if i run `rosservice call static_map` where `static_map` is running on the basestation, it says it's `Unable to communicate with service /static_map`. I've set ROS_IP on the other machines to be the VPN IP address and not the WAN IP, which fixed things like running `rosnode info` on a node running on a VPN-connected machine but this doesn't seem to help with services.

Is it just the username being an issue, or are there more steps needed to set up VPN connected computers besides setting up the connection and setting the proper `ROS_MASTER_URI`, `ROS_IP`, and any necessary entries in `/etc/hosts`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12606/ros-connectivity-and-usernames/) by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS communications do not require username or authentification.  Read the [technical overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Technical%20Overview)

The only thing which requires SSH username and keys is [roslaunch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch).  All other communications simply require port numbers.

There appears to be an issue with something like routing or name lookup and services.  If you can describe how to reproduce it we can take a closer look.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-03-05**:
Agreed; this is probably a problem with name resolution on your network. Running 'rosservice info ' should show you which hostname clients are using when creating service clients. You should make sure that this name resolves properly on all machines.

**Comment by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on 2012-03-06**:
It was probably a routing issue, I actually am not sure at the moment if the issue still exists because I'm not in the lab at the moment but I think somehow I figured it out or it magically fixed itself.